# An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, spree-auth-devise, spree-paypal-express

In Spree 3.0 "Mail Method Settings" not available by default.

Rails version 4.2.0

Using **"gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings', branch: '3-0-stable'"** in admin panel one link generate in Configuration menu "Mail Method settings".

All configuration done. But when Click on "Test Mail"  Button it gives error 
**"An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address."**

Comment: I recommend not using spree_mail_settings and configuring your mail using ActionMailer. spree_mail_settings is for older versions of Spree, and was removed from the main code base due to confusion like this. My guess is that spree_mail_settings hasn't been updated for Rails 4.2. You should file an issue on the project if you're intent on using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is a total hack but this is how i got past this issue for my tests.  i had to hard code the 'from_address' in order_mailer.confirm_email method to what i would enter anyway in the admin section.  here is my code:

```
  def confirm_email(order, resend = false)
    @order = order.respond_to?(:id) ? order : Spree::Order.find(order)
    subject = (resend ? "[#{Spree.t(:resend).upcase}] " : '')
    subject += "#{Spree::Store.current.name} #{Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.subject')} ##{@order.number}"
    mail(to: @order.email, from: 'yourfromaddress@yourdomain.com', subject: subject)
  end
```

you would think there should be an easy way to set this value for the test config but i couldn't figure it out.